# Passing the object back in a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

There's a number of questions and answers about how to avoid retain cycles when accessing self inside a block such as this...

```
MYObject *obj = [[MYObject alloc] init];
__weak typeof(obj) weakObj = obj;
obj.completionBlock = ^(){
    NSLog(@"my message %@", weakObj.message);
};
```

But with classes like NSTask the termination handler actually has the task object included in the block callback...

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
// Set up task...
task.terminationHandler = ^(NSTask *aTask){
    NSLog(@"Task Launch Path: %@", aTask.launchPath);
};

[task launch];
```

So the question is how is this object sent back to itself internally?
is a weak reference to itself or a copy, or something all together different?

```
 __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
 _terminationHandler(weakSelf);
```

Or...

```
_terminationHandler([self copy]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time you have to worry about retain cycles caused by a block is when the block, acting as a closure, *captures* something *external* to the block, such as `self`. But in the example you give, nothing external to the block is being captured:

```
task.terminationHandler = ^(NSTask *aTask){
    NSLog(@"Task Launch Path: %@", aTask.launchPath);
};
```

In the block, you are not referring to `task` - you are referring to `aTask`. Well, `aTask` is not external to the block; it is *internal* to the block — it is a parameter passed into the block. Thus there is no capture and no retain cycle: `task` is retaining a `terminationHandler` which makes *no reference* to `task`, so there is no danger of circularity. This is exactly *why* the task hands you a reference to itself as a parameter of the block - so that you *can* refer to it.

If you were to refer to `task` in the block (instead of `aTask`) and run the Analyzer, sure enough, you'd get a warning about the danger of a retain cycle!

Comment: So it need not be a `__weak` reference, or a `copy` when passed into the block as a parameter, it can simply be self?

Comment: Sure. Merely passing or receiving an object as a parameter has no memory management implications. If it did, you'd be going mad dealing with it all the time! You may be over-thinking this stuff.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the answer. If you wouldn't mind updating the answer with the unnecessary nature of `__weak` or `copy`, and that you can simply use `self` as a parameter, I'd be happy to mark it as "accepted"

Comment: In my view, what I said is much deeper, more penetrating, and more educational than merely talking about "weak" and "copy" and "self" as a parameter. I'm trying to jar you out of a total misconception here, and steer you on the right mental path. If I've failed, I've failed. So, if you don't like my answer, don't accept it; that is entirely your privilege. But please don't try to put words in my mouth or tell me how to write.

Comment: I sincerely apologize if that was your sense of my request. My initial question probably should have been clearer. There are may Q and A's talking about capturing self inside a block but none that address the specific situation where the `self` is passed into a block as  a parameter is the same object, I was concerned that since the self being sent as a parameter was equal to the object an underlying retention cycle hidden from the compiler could be present. You did answer the question, the only reason I suggested this was so future answers seekers would see the information in the answer body.

Comment: The comments will probably remain, so our post-mortem analysis will not be lost to history.